# Parsing XML which as same child node with unix timestamp as prefix in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Could anyone help me in parsing the below XML ?
I have XML that has childnode_ which is appended with dynamic unix time-stamp for each node.

```
    <data>
     <childnode_1432157610>
         <element>A</element>
     </childnode_1432157610>
    <childnode_1532157610>
     <element>A</element>
    </childnode_1532157610>
    <childnode_1632157610>
     <element>A</element>
    </childnode_1632157610>
</data>
```

Comment: read it like any xml file

Comment: Is this correct? It uses the same `childnode_` tag for openning and closing.